# How to create a LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> as a Spring bean?

Tags: java, spring

I need to pass a LinkedBlockingQueue as a bean to a number of other beans. Is it possible to define one in XML. It's normal definition is simply:

```
new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can just do that:

```
<bean id="queue" class="java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue" />
```

I don't think you can explicitly say that it holds Runnable instances as the queue will be created at run time where Java generics is not visible.

**EDIT**: You can also pass constructor arguments:

```
<bean id="queue" class="java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue" >
  <constructor-arg type="int"><value>10</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

This will limit the queue size to 10.